# Regression adding interaction term reduce T-value

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

I have the following two models:

```
y~x1
y~x1+x1:x2
```

the linear regression result is as follow

> y~x1

```
                   coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -4.45e-07   7.62e-08     -5.840      0.000   -5.94e-07   -2.96e-07
x1             0.0146   4.08e-05    357.696      0.000       0.015       0.015
```

> y~x1+x1:x2

```
                             coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept          -5.856e-07   7.59e-08     -7.715      0.000   -7.34e-07   -4.37e-07
x1                 -4.363e-05      0.000     -0.384      0.701      -0.000       0.000
x1:x2               0.0347      0.000    137.950      0.000       0.034       0.035
```

My question is, in the first result, the t-value is larger than the interaction term in the second, why this is possible? And in the second regression, `x1` is has almost zero t-value, does that mean it is better to use x1:x2 as a regressor than x1 alone? The most confusing thing for me is still why the t-value drop dramatically for the interaction term.